# Particle.io argon delay time as var

Tags: arduino

I have everything working wonderfully but I want to accomplish one more thing and I'm not sure how to go about it.

Part one to this question:

Under `command=="loops"` I have a `delay()` function. I want to be able to sent this time from the dashboard or url. Example would be… (written in php action of CURL):

```
$url =  “https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/".$my_device."/".$zone_name."?access_token=”.$my_token;
```

Would my URL be changed to

```
$url = “https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/".$my_device."/".$zone_name."?dealy=100&access_token=”.$my_token;
```

If so how do I assign the var to my delay?

Part 2 of the question is,
I don’t know if delay is the right option. I remember reading something about delay causing a lockout and the device cant do anything while this is going on. If this is the case this will not work as I will have other functions that will trigger other events. What other functions do I have to solve this problem?

```cpp
int zoneone = D5;
int zonetwo = D6;
int zonethree = D7;
int zonefour = D8;


void setup()
{

// define pine as output high/low not digital read
   pinMode(zoneone, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(zonetwo, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(zonethree, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(zonefour, OUTPUT);


// creates the webhook actions 
   Particle.function("zoneone",zones_one);
   Particle.function("zonetwo",zones_two);
   Particle.function("zonethree",zones_three);
   Particle.function("zonefour",zones_four);  


// sets everything to off just to make sure we are in the right state 
   digitalWrite(zoneone, LOW);
   digitalWrite(zonetwo, LOW);
   digitalWrite(zonethree, LOW);
   digitalWrite(zonefour, LOW);

}

void loop()
{
   // Nothing to do here
}

// zone one action
int zones_one(String command) {

    if (command=="on") {
        digitalWrite(zoneone,HIGH);
        return 1;
    }
     if (command=="loops") {
         
        digitalWrite(zoneone,HIGH);
// need to change this to a delay(var);
     delay(75); 
        digitalWrite(zoneone,LOW);
        return 2;
    }
    else if (command=="off") {
        digitalWrite(zoneone,LOW);
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}

// zone two action
int zones_two(String command) {

    if (command=="on") {
        digitalWrite(zonetwo,HIGH);
        return 1;
    }
    else if (command=="off") {
        digitalWrite(zonetwo,LOW);
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}

// zone three action
int zones_three(String command) {

    if (command=="on") {
        digitalWrite(zonethree,HIGH);
        return 1;
    }
    else if (command=="off") {
        digitalWrite(zonethree,LOW);
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}

// zone four action
int zones_four(String command) {

    if (command=="on") {
        digitalWrite(zonefour,HIGH);
        return 1;
    }
    else if (command=="off") {
        digitalWrite(zonefour,LOW);
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does your code call the `zone` functions? You should pass the `delay` just as you pass `zone_name` and `command` to your code.